# Count the occurrence of a word in an incoming stream of characters

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was asked this question during an interview and although I am good in DS&Algo but this one I was not able to solve. This is an interesting question anyways so posting it.

Problem: You have an incoming stream of characters and you need to count the occurrences of a word. You have only one API to read from the stream which is stream.next_char() which return "\0" if there is none.

```
int count_occurrences(Stream stream, String word) {
// you have only one function provided from Stream class that you can use to 
// read one char at a time, no length/size etc.
// stream.next_char() - return "\0" if end
}
```

Input: "aabckjhabcc"
Word: "abc"
Output: 2

Comment: how "word" is defined? I mean input stream in your example has no delimiters, so it does not contain word "abc" in my opinion.

Comment: Easy (suboptimal) answer: Keep a ring buffer with the last `lengthOfTheWord` characters in it, and do a full string comparison after each call to `next_char()`.  Hint for a better answer: Are there substring search algorithms that only ever examine characters from the text in increasing order, without ever skipping over some character?

Comment: Sounds like you want a DFA to parse the string and count the number of visits to final states.

Comment: Another way to solve is to use [Knuth-Morris-Prath algo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). However it will need to take O(n) memory.

Comment: @Rahul.B, I expect that there is a requirement to tell exactly how many occurrences are so far while you take next character. Also there is a restriction on time complexity and memory. Provided no restrictions exist why can't we just read the stream, check for every position if the word occurrence happen in this position with trivial algorithm comparing  characters one by one. (O(length(strem) * length(word)) solution).

Comment: @IvanGritsenko; Thats the trivial algorithm we need to find. The buffer solution by @j_random_hacker looks good to me.

Comment: Another way to look at this question, is that the interviewer was a jerk...I would not have bothered to even answer it. Having said that, I  am already looking at how a "ring buffer" can be implemented in Java and Scala. Finally, having written the Streaming Analytics (Spark Streaming) implementation of one of the largest Infrastructure companies in Europe, I see absolutely no correlation between said interview question, and the real world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question is related to the idea of 
matching strings using a finite state model of computation.

This question can be solved by using the KMP string 
matching algorithm.

The KMP algorithm tries to find matches in a text string of a pattern 
string, by considering how much prefix of pattern
is still matched even if we find a mismatch at some point.

For determining "how much prefix can still be matched" if 
we encounter a mismatch after matching upto index i in pattern,
a failure function is built in advance. (Please refer the below code
for building of failure function values)

This failure function will tell for each index i of pattern,
how much prefix of the pattern can still be matched even if
we encounter a mismatch after index i.

The idea is to figure out what is the length of longest proper prefix of pattern
that is also a suffix of it for each substring of pattern denoted by 1 to i 
indices where i ranges from 1 to n.

I am using string indices to start from 1.

Thus the failure function value for first character of any pattern
is 0. (i.e. no character has been matched so far).

For subsequent characters, for each index i = 2 to n, we see what
is the length of the longest
proper prefix of the substring of pattern[1...i] which is also
a suffix of that substring of pattern[1...i].

Suppose our pattern is "aac", then the failure function value for 
index 1 is 0 (no match yet), and the failure function value
for index 2 is 1, ( the length of the longest proper prefix which is same as
longest proper suffix for "aa" is 1)

For pattern "ababac" the failure function value for index 1 is 0,
index 2 is 0, index 3 is 1 (as the third index 'a' is the same as
first index 'a'), for index 4 is 2 (as "ab" at indices 1 and 2 are same
as "ab" at indices 3 and 4) , and for index 5 is 3 ("aba" at indices[1...3] 
is the same as "aba" at indices [3...5] ). For index 6, the failure function value is 0.

Here is the code (C++) for building the failure function and matching
a text (or stream) using it :

```
/* Assuming that string indices start from 1 for both pattern and text. */
/* Firstly build the failure function. */
int s = 1;
int t = 0;  

/* n denotes the length of the pattern */
int *f = new int[n+1];
f[1] = 0;   

for (s = 1; s < n; s++) {
    while (t > 0 && pattern[t + 1] != pattern[s + 1]) {
        t = f[t];
    }
    if (pattern[t + 1] == pattern[s + 1]) {
        t++;
        f[s + 1] = t;
    }
    else {
        f[s + 1] = 0;           
    }
}

/* Now start reading characters from the stream */
int count = 0;
char current_char = stream.next_char();

/* s denotes the index of pattern upto which we have found match in text */
/* initially its 0 i.e. no character has been matched yet. */
s = 0; 
while (current_char != '\0') {

    /* IF previously, we had matched upto a certain number of
       characters, and then failed, we return s to the point
       which is the longest prefix that still might be matched.

       (spaces between string are just for clarity)
       For e.g., if pattern is              "a  b  a  b  a  a" 
       & its failure returning index is     "0  0  1  2  3  1"

       and we encounter 
       the text like :      "x  y  z  a  b  a  b  a  b  a  a" 
              indices :      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11

       after matching the substring "a  b  a  b  a", starting at
       index 4 of text, we are successful upto index 8  but we fail
       at index 9, the next character at index 9 of text is 'b'
       but in our pattern which should have been 'a'.Thus, the index
       in pattern which has been matched till now is 5 ( a  b  a  b  a)
                                                         1  2  3  4  5
       Now, we see that the failure returning index at index 5 of 
       pattern is 3, which means that the text is still matched upto
       index 3 of pattern (a  b  a), not from the initial starting 
       index 4 of text, but starting from index 6 of text.

       Thus we continue searching assuming that our next starting index
       in text is 6, eventually finding the match starting from index 6
       upto index 11.    

       */
        while (s > 0 && current_char != pattern[s + 1]) {
            s = f[s];
        }
        if (current_char == pattern[s + 1]) s++; /* We test the next character after the currently
                                                    matched portion of pattern with the current 
                                                    character of text , if it matches, we increase
                                                    the size of our matched portion by 1*/
        if (s == n) {
            count++;
        }
        current_char = stream.next_char();
}

printf("Count is %d\n", count);
```

`

Note: This method will be helpful in finding out counts even in overlapping pattern occurrences. For example, the word "aba" as two occurrences
in the stream "ababa".

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution is to use buffer with up-to word.length() symbols:

```
static int count_occurrences(final Stream stream, final String word) {
    int found = 0;

    char c;
    String tmpWord = "";
    while ((c = stream.next_char()) != 0) {
        tmpWord += c;
        if (tmpWord.length() > word.length()) {
            tmpWord = tmpWord.substring(1);
        }
        if (tmpWord.equals(word)) {
            found++;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

complexity is O(N*M), memory O(M)

Comment: Try it with: word = "ababc", stream = "abababc"

Comment: Will it work for overlapping words? For example, will it find both occurrences of "abba" in "abbabba"?

Answer (score 0):

```
int count_occurrences(Stream stream, String word) {
    int occurrence = 0;
    int current_index = 0;
    int word_length = word.length();
    char[] word_chars = word.toCharArray();

    char c = stream.next_char();
    while(c != '\0') {
        if( c == word_chars[current_index] ) {
            current_index++;
            if(current_index >= word_length) {
                occurrence++;
                current_index = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            current_index = 0;
            if( c == word_chars[current_index] ) {
                current_index++;
            }
        }
        c = stream.next_char();

    }
    return occurrence;
}
```

Comment: Try it with: word = "ababc", stream = "abababc" – @obe

Comment: Good catch indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
int count_occurrences(Stream stream, String word) {
    // you have only one function provided from Stream class that you can use to 
    // read one char at a time, no length/size etc.
    // stream.next_char() - return "\0" if end

    List<int> positions = new List<int>();

    int counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        char ch = stream.next_char();
        if (ch == '\0') return counter;

        if (ch == word.charAt(0)) {
            positions.add(0);
        }

        int i = 0;
        while (i < positions.length) {
            int pos = positions[i];

            if (word.charAt(pos) != ch) {
                positions.remove(i);
                continue;
            }

            pos++;
            if (pos == word.length()) {
                positions.remove(i);
                counter++;
                continue;
            }

            positions[i] = pos;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose worst case time will be O(N*N) and memory O(N)

Answer (score 0):

What they were looking for (probably) is either Rabin-Karp or Knuth-Morris-Pratt. Both need a single pass with very small overhead. If the pattern is large they will be obvious wins in terms of speed since the complexity is `O(stream_length)`.

Rabbin-Karp relies on hashes that you can update in O(1) for the next character. Can give you false positives if the hash isn't very good or when the stream is very long (hash collisions).

Knuth-Morris-Pratt reliest on computing the length of the longest prefix that is also a suffix for every position in your pattern. This needs O(n) memory for storing these results but that's it.

Look them up in wikipedia under string pattern matching for more details and implementations.