# Searching for an exact string match in a (arbitrary large) stream - C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, string-matching

I am building a simple multi-server for string matching. I handle multiple clients at the same time by using sockets and select. The only job that the server does is this: a client connects to a server and sends a needle (of size less than 10 GB) and a haystack (of arbitrary size) as a stream through a network socket. Needle and haystack are an arbitrary binary data.

Server needs to search the haystack for all occurrences of the needle (as an exact string match) and sends a number of needle matches back to the client. Server needs to process clients on the fly and be able to handle any input in a reasonable time (that is a search algorithm have to have a linear time complexity).

To do this I obviously need to split the haystack into a small parts (possibly smaller than the needle) in order to process them as they are coming through the network socket. That is I would need a search algorithm that is able to handle a string, that is split into parts and search in it, the same way as strstr(...) does.

I could not find any standard C or C++ library function nor a Boost library object that could handle a string by parts. If I am not mistaken, algorithms in strstr(), string.find() and Boost searching/knuth_morris_pratt.hpp are only able to handle the search, when a whole haystack is in a continuous block of memory. Or is there some trick, that I could use to search a string by parts that I am missing? Do you guys know of any C/C++ library, that is able to cope with such a large needles and haystacks resp. that is able to handle haystack streams or search in haystack by parts?

I did not find any useful library by googling and hence I was forced to create my own variation of Knuth Morris Pratt algorithm, that is able to remember its own state (shown bellow). However I do not find it to be an optimal solution, as a well tuned string searching algorithm would surely perform better in my opinion, and it would be a less worry for a debugging later.

So my question is:
Is there some more elegant way to search in a large haystack stream by parts, other than creating my own search algorithm? Is there any trick how to use a standard C string library for this? Is there some C/C++ library that is specialized for a this kind of task?

Here is a (part of) code of my midified KMP algorithm:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

class knuth_morris_pratt {
    const char* const needle;
    const size_t needle_len;
    const int* const lps; // a longest proper suffix table (skip table)

// suffix_len is an ofset of a longest haystack_part suffix matching with
// some prefix of the needle. suffix_len myst be shorter than needle_len.
// Ofset is defined as a last matching character in a needle.
    size_t suffix_len;
    size_t match_count; // a number of needles found in haystack

public:
    inline knuth_morris_pratt(const char* needle, size_t len) : 
            needle(needle), needle_len(len),
            lps( build_lps_array() ), suffix_len(0),
            match_count(len == 0 ? 1 : 0)    {  }
    inline ~knuth_morris_pratt() {  free((void*)lps);   }

    void search_part(const char* haystack_part, size_t hp_len); // processes a given part of the haystack stream
    inline size_t get_match_count() { return match_count; }

private:
    const int* build_lps_array();
};

// Worst case complexity: linear space, linear time

// see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kmp-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/
// see article: KNUTH D.E., MORRIS (Jr) J.H., PRATT V.R., 1977, Fast pattern matching in strings
void knuth_morris_pratt::search_part(const char* haystack_part, size_t hp_len) {
    if(needle_len == 0) {
        match_count += hp_len;
        return;
    }

    const char* hs = haystack_part;

    size_t i = 0; // index for txt[]
    size_t j = suffix_len; // index for pat[]
    while (i < hp_len) {
        if (needle[j] == hs[i]) {
            j++;
            i++;
        }

        if (j == needle_len) {
            // a needle found
            match_count++;
            j = lps[j - 1];
        }
        else if (i < hp_len && needle[j] != hs[i]) {
            // Do not match lps[0..lps[j-1]] characters,
            // they will match anyway
            if (j != 0)
                j = lps[j - 1];
            else
                i = i + 1;
        }
    }

    suffix_len = j;
}

const int* knuth_morris_pratt::build_lps_array() {
    int* const new_lps = (int*)malloc(needle_len);
//    check_cond_fatal(new_lps != NULL, "Unable to alocate memory in knuth_morris_pratt(..)");

    // length of the previous longest prefix suffix
    size_t len = 0;
    new_lps[0] = 0; // lps[0] is always 0

    // the loop calculates lps[i] for i = 1 to M-1
    size_t i = 1;
    while (i < needle_len) {
        if (needle[i] == needle[len]) {
            len++;
            new_lps[i] = len;
            i++;
        }
        else // (pat[i] != pat[len])
        {
            // This is tricky. Consider the example.
            // AAACAAAA and i = 7. The idea is similar
            // to search step.
            if (len != 0) {
                len = new_lps[len - 1];

                // Also, note that we do not increment
                // i here
            }
            else // if (len == 0)
            {
                new_lps[i] = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    return new_lps;
}


int main() 
{
    const char* needle = "lorem";
    const char* p1 = "sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium qui dolo";
    const char* p2 = "rem ipsum quia dolor sit amet";
    const char* p3 = "dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?";
    knuth_morris_pratt searcher(needle, strlen(needle));
    searcher.search_part(p1, strlen(p1));
    searcher.search_part(p2, strlen(p2));
    searcher.search_part(p3, strlen(p3));

    printf("%d \n", (int)searcher.get_match_count());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this some kind of school assignment? It would be faster to do the search locally than to send data over the network.

Comment: Why do you use `malloc`? Also, you don't check if `malloc` failed. I think you sadly have to store full needle anyway. As for haystack I don't like the "divide into parts" part, I would imagine your function working on a stream - it would take a function pointer that reads from the stream of incoming haystack characters. It is up to that algorithm implementation how big if any haystack "parts" should be. What does your function should return? Ie. a bool if the string was found or not, or a ex. position in the haystack where the needle is found?

Comment: The search algorithm should return a number of needle matches in a haystack and optionally the offsets of needles in a haystack. Haystack can have 1TB, hence if searching locally, the problem is the same: I would have to split the file to a reasonable big chunks and search by parts.

Comment: what about the BNDM algo?

Comment: Isn't BNDM O(mn)?

Comment: KMP only looks at each character of the haystack once and never goers back. So a string is not needed, a linear stream is enough.

Comment: Even if you are using an algorithm that requires backtracking of the haystack, you only need a needle worth of haystack buffer. Shift out characters that are completely checked. A larger buffer requires less shifts. Perhaps a more efficient method would be to use two such buffers A and B, and an interface that sees either AB or BA as a single contiguous buffer. Switch between AB and BA as soon as one of the buffers is completely checked. No buffer copying is needed in this case.

Comment: Is there any string search library with KMP already implemmented in this fashion?

Comment: [boost kmp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/boost/algorithm/searching/knuth_morris_pratt.hpp) accepts a pair of iterators. It does require knowing the length of the haystack though, but it is easy to modify to eliminate this requirement.

Comment: BNDM is O(n) as KMP

Comment: The [Boyer-Moore-Horspool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm) algorithm can easily be adapted to work on streams. You can find multiple implementations with a search.

Comment: Boyer-Moore-Horspool is O(nm) which is unusable for this case, because if a maliscious client sent 5MB needle and 1GB file constructed in a such way, that the worst computation time would be reached, this would block other clients in select loop. (a specially constructed input for O(nm) alg could have a runtime in years...).

Comment: I found a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087764/count-the-occurrence-of-a-word-in-an-incoming-stream-of-characters

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [BNDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm), which has same performances as KMP:

- O(m) for preprocessing
- O(n) for matching.

It is used for [nrgrep](https://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~gnavarro/ps/spe01.pdf), the sources of which can be found [here](https://www.dcc.uchile.cl/~gnavarro/software) which containts C sources.

**C source for BNDM algo** are [here](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/bndm.html).

See [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866706000967) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If I have well understood your problem, you want to search if a large `std::string` received part by part contains a substring.

If it is the case, I think you can store for each iteration the overlapping section between two contiguous received packets. And then you just have to check for each iteration that either the overlap or the packet contains the desired pattern to find.

In the example below, I consider the following `contains()` function to search a pattern in a `std::string`:

```
bool contains(const std::string & str, const std::string & pattern)
{
    bool found(false);

    if(!pattern.empty() && (pattern.length() < str.length()))
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; !found && (i <= str.length()-pattern.length()); ++i)
        {
            if((str[i] == pattern[0]) && (str.substr(i, pattern.length()) == pattern))
            {
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

**Example:**

```
std::string pattern("something");            // The pattern we want to find
std::string end_of_previous_packet("");      // The first part of overlapping section
std::string beginning_of_current_packet(""); // The second part of overlapping section

std::string overlap;                         // The string to store the overlap at each iteration

bool found(false);

while(!found && !all_data_received())          // stop condition
{
    // Get the current packet
    std::string packet = receive_part();

    // Set the beginning of the current packet
    beginning_of_current_packet = packet.substr(0, pattern.length());

    // Build the overlap
    overlap = end_of_previous_packet + beginning_of_current_packet;

    // If the overlap or the packet contains the pattern, we found a match
    if(contains(overlap, pattern) || contains(packet, pattern))
        found = true;

    // Set the end of previous packet for the next iteration
    end_of_previous_packet = packet.substr(packet.length()-pattern.length());
}
```

Of course, in this example I made the assumption that the method `receive_part()` already exists. Same thing for the `all_data_received()` function. **It is just an example to illustrate the idea.**

I hope it will help you to find a solution.